# Scala type system and inheritance

Tags: scala

Take the following Scala code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

class father[T,K:Numeric] extends HashMap[T,K]
class sonA[T] extends father[T, Long]
class sonB[T] extends father[T, Double]

def func_sonA[T](x: List[T]) = {
    // code
    new sonA[T]
}

def func_sonB[T](x: List[T]) = {
    // code
    new sonB[T]
}

val strList = List("one", "two", "three", "four")
val intList = List(1,2,3,4)
val both:List[List[Any]] = List(strList, intList)

val mapped = both.map(x =>
    x match {
        case i:List[String] => func_sonA(i)
        case i:List[Int] => func_sonB(i)
    }
)
```

The type for `mapped` is: `List[father[_ >: String with Int, _ >: Long with Double : AnyVal]]`.

What exactly does `_>:` means?

What's the idea behind `String with Int` and what is it good for?
Seems that it can grow indefinitely (`String with Int with Double With Long with...`).

How can I specify the type of `mapped` to be just `List[father]` or `List[father[Any, Any]]` without losing the type information?

I'm having a bit of a difficulty finding answers since search results for phrases `_>:` aren't very relevant.

EDIT:

To illustrate the actual problem its causing, I want to use a function with a `List[father[Any, Any]]` input but I can't pass `mapped`. I'm getting a type mismatch error.

Function:

```
def bar(x: List[father[Any, Any]]) = {
    println(x)
}
bar(mapped)
```

Error:

```
Error:(52, 9) type mismatch;
 found   : List[father[_ >: String with Int, _ >: Long with Double <: AnyVal]]
 required: List[father[Any,Any]]
    bar(mapped)
        ^
```

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but [this](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#bounds) can help explain what `>:` means.

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: So did it help you to solve your problem?

Comment: @thwiegan Not the answer I was hoping for but it does answer my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_ >: String with Int` basically means, that the type is either `String` OR `Int`. In case of `List[String]` you get back a `sonA[String]` and therefore a `father[String, Long]`, in case of `List[Int]` respectively a `sonB[Int]` and therefore a `father[Int,Double]` so you end up with a `father` where the first type is either `String` or `Int` and the second type is either `Long` or `Double`.

Regarding your other question:

> How can I specify the type of mapped to be just `List[father]` or `List[father[Any, Any]]` without losing the type information?

Why do you want that? The current type is actually more specific than just `List[father]` or `List[father[Any,Any]].`

**EDIT**

Okay now I know what you want.

Basically what you want to achieve is that this becomes possible:

```
val mapped: List[father[Any,Any]] = both.map(x =>
  x match {
    case i:List[String] => func_sonA(i)
    case i:List[Int] => func_sonB(i)
  }
)
```

The problem here is, that currently with

```
class father[T,K] extends HashMap[T,K]
```

The scala compiler does not know that e.g. `father[String,Long]` is supposed to be a subtype of `father[Any,Any]` (this does not automatically result from `String` and `Long` being subtypes of `Any`). 
So, to tell Scala that the above should be applicable, you need the class `father` to be covariant in **both** type parameters:

```
class father[+T,+K]
```

The problem with that is, that you are extending `HashMap[T,K]`. But this class is only covariant in the **first** type Parameter `T`, but not `K`.

So this code here actually works, but it is not extending `HashMap`:

```
class father[+T,+K]
class sonA[T] extends father[T, Long]
class sonB[T] extends father[T, Double]

def func_sonA[T](x: List[T]) = {
  // code
  new sonA[T]
}

def func_sonB[T](x: List[T]) = {
  // code
  new sonB[T]
}

val strList = List("one", "two", "three", "four")
val intList = List(1,2,3,4)
val both = List(strList, intList)

val mapped: List[father[Any,Any]] = both.map(x =>
  x match {
    case i:List[String] => func_sonA(i)
    case i:List[Int] => func_sonB(i)
  }
)

def bar(x: List[father[Any, Any]]) = {
  println(x)
}
bar(mapped)
```

Further readings on covariance [here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala/).

Comment: This simplified version has only `String with Int`, in general it could be anything and in my opinion `Any` would be more readable than `String with Int with Double with ...`.
Also I'd like to understand why it behaves like that so I can get a better understanding of the type system.

Comment: Scala always tries to find the lowest bounds for a type. In that case it is this construct. As long as you don't write it yourself, you won't need to read it and can just handle it as if it were father[Any,Any]. For further research you can read up on scala type inference.

Comment: Edited main post with a better reason to why I'd want it to be `[Any, Any]`.